# getting the height of the specified element returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to alert the height of the specified element below is what I tried but returns me undefined unfortunately.

```
var dl;
$(window).load(function(){
    dl = $("#dashboard_left").height();

});

$(document).ready(function(){
    alert(dl);
});
```

so first, i set the variable 'dl' to global and then on window load, store the height of a div that has an id of 'dashboard_left' on the variable named 'dl' as it returns '0' if set on 'document.ready' and then alert the 'dl' variable on 'document.ready' but sadly and unfortunately it returns me 'undefined' any ideas, help, suggestions, clues?

Comment: because window load will be fired after document ready....

Comment: so any alternative way to get the height of the specified div that has no specified height?

Comment: do your second part of the problem also in a window load handler

Comment: solved now. thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score -2):

It's because `.load` and `.ready` are firing at different times and one of two things are happening:

- either `ready` fires before `load` which means that `dl` hasn't been set yet (it's undefined because `load` hasn't set it to anything yet)
- or when `load` fires the document isn't ready yet, which means that you're trying to get the height of a non-existent element.

try setting `dl` just before you alert it, and it will be the value you want.